# Dynamically Pass List of Object As A Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, dynamic, parameter-passing

I've a method where I pass list of object as the following:

```
public void BindGridView(int pageIndex, List<Users> lstUsers, GridView grd, Panel pl)
{

}
```

See in the above the list `List<Users>` is fixed, so I can pass it statically in a method. I'll use the same method to show data in a grid and planning to pass dynamically whenever there are other list of objects. In the above way, I've to declare all the list as below:

```
public void BindGridView(int pageIndex, List<Groups> lstGroups, GridView grd, Panel pl)
{
}

public void BindGridView(int pageIndex, List<GroupDetails> lstGroupDetails, GridView grd, Panel pl)
{
}
```

Is ther any way where I can declare it dynamically something like `List<Dynamic>`, say for utility purpose, so every time I can pass any list of object?

Comment: Read about generics and make the method generic and pass `List<T>`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gilad Green and I got it. One for thing, could I declare a list like this `List<T> lst = null;` and tried, it says, **The type or namespace 'T' could not be found**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're most likely looking for generics here. i.e:

```
public void BindGridView<T>(int pageIndex, List<T> lstUsers, GridView grd, Panel pl)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for it @Aominè and this is exactly what I was looking for. One for thing, could I declare a list like this `List<T> lst = null;` and tried, it says, **The type or namespace 'T' could not be found**.

Comment: you can only do that if it's inside the scope of the method, however `T` doesn't exist outside the method. also, note that `T` is just a placeholder so when you're calling the method you need to pass in the concrete type i.e `List<GroupDetails>`

Comment: if you want `T` to be visible through the class then you may need to generalise the class itself which would enable you to use `T` throughout the class. have a look at [**Introduction to Generics (C# Programming Guide)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/introduction-to-generics)